# How to read from file into an object (constructor)

Tags: java

So i got a class called `Car` where I store information related to a car.
It looks like this

```
public class Car {
    private String reg;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private int millage;
   private String service;

    //Constructor for the Car Class 
   public Car (String reg, String model,int year, String name, String date, int millage, String service){
       this.reg = reg;
       this.millage = millage;
       this.date = date;
       this.service = service;
       this.name = name;
       this.model = model;
       this.year = year;
}
```

After the user enters information about the car all the information is stored in an array list and the data within the array list is printed to a .txt file for storage.

**How the textfile looks so far**

```
Ford-ERI56Y-2003-Tuva Larsson-2020/24/01-Large Service    
Volvo -JDV810-1999-Åsa Eriksson-2020/24/01-Small Service
```

I want to be able to scan the text file and add the content of the file back in an `ArrayList` for later usage.

I have this code so far

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       String read;
         while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String [] carParts = read.split("-");

carList.add(read)


         }


}
```

This doesn't work since the `ArrayList` uses `Car` and not `String`

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: You need to create a Car, by invoking its constructor, and passing the required arguments, which are in the carParts array. Then you need to add that car to the list: `Car car = new Car(carParts[0], ...); carList.add(car);`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

Made some changes to your `Car` class so it now looks like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Car {

    private final String registration;
    public String getRegistration() { return registration; }

    private final String model;
    public String getModel() { return model; }

    private final Integer year;
    public Integer getYear() { return year; }

    private final String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }

    private final LocalDate date;
    public LocalDate getDate() { return date; }

    private final Integer mileage;
    public Integer getMileage() { return mileage; }

    private final String service;
    public String getService() { return service; }

    public Car(String registration, String model, Integer year, String name, LocalDate date, Integer mileage,
    String service) {
    this.registration = registration;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.mileage = mileage;
    this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Car{" +
        "registration='" + registration + '\'' +
        ", model='" + model + '\'' +
        ", year=" + year +
        ", name='" + name + '\'' +
        ", date=" + date +
        ", mileage=" + mileage +
        ", service='" + service + '\'' +
        '}';
    }

}
```

Also the example .txt file containing the entries was missing a couple of columns, so I went ahead and add those too:

```
ERI56Y-Ford-2003-Tuva Larsson-2020/24/01-60000-Large Service
JDV810-Volvo-1999-Åsa Eriksson-2020/24/01-750000-Small Service`
```

Now that the pojo and the text file are OK, reading from this and creating a list of cars is very easy. Check the example below:

```
private static List<Car> readFromFile(String filePath) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        return lines
        .map(line -> line.split("-"))
        .map(parts -> new Car(parts[0], parts[1],
            Integer.valueOf(parts[2]), parts[3],
            LocalDate.parse(parts[4], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/dd/MM")),
            Integer.valueOf(parts[5]), parts[6]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

This will effectively do the following:

1. Open up a `Stream<String>` using `Files#lines`
2. Mapping the contents of the stream to a splitting action
3. Mapping the produced array of strings into a new `Car` object
4. Collecting to a list

An example call of this would look like:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    readFromFile(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/cars.txt").forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```